# Typescript: using await when fetching but returning non-Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

If I have typescript class that has the following data:

```
private _initialNames: any;

async getData(): Promise<any> {
   
   const resp = await fetch(url);
   const { data } = await resp.json();

   this._initialNames = data.reduce(
        (acc: any, curr: any) => ({
            ...acc,
            [curr.name]: {
                found: curr.found,
                age: curr?.age,              
            }
        }),
        {}
    );   
    
    return this._initialNames;
}
```

when I call this function, why do I use `await getData()`; since it's returning an array, not a Promise?  I know I have to use `async` since I am awaiting a fetch inside but when I call the actual function , do I still await it?

Comment: All async functions automatically become a function that returns a promise, that returns what you return in the function. The promise aspect is baked in the cake once you use the async keyword. You will need to `await getData()`

Comment: "*it's returning an array, not a Promise?*" - oh really? Have you tried it? Also the type declaration disagrees as well.